# How to draw on the background in a vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to make an extension that draw lines on the background? You can decorate a lot of thing but I can't find a way to draw colored lines.
I would like to see the flow of my data (inspired by visual programming).

Something like that (but the like drawn under the text) :

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind vscode is an add-on to Electron, which is a webbrowser in a desktop raiment. So what you see are webpages and hence everything what's possible on a webpage (with a node.js basement) is also [possible in vscode](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) - at least in theory. I say "in theory" because after all vscode is a text editor and limits interaction in a way that supports this goal. So, what you can is either some drawing/graphics or add extensions that work in normal editor pages. You certainly don't want to write your own text editor interface within vscode.